# <span> indent wrapped text

Tags: css

So I'm simulating a table layout with a div and a couple spans inside it. I'd like the span on the right to indent any text that wraps.  I've tried a few things and can't get it to work.  Any help would be appreciated.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2Wbuv/

HTML

```
<div class="display-element">
    <span class="display-label">Field 1</span>
    <span class="display-field">This is my string of data, some times it is pretty long.  Sometimes it is not.  This one is.</span>
</div>
<div class="display-element">
    <span class="display-label">Field 2</span>
    <span class="display-field">This is another string of data.</span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.display-element        {}

.display-label          {display: inline-block;
                         width: 100px;
                         padding-left: 5px;}

.display-field          {display: inline;}
```

Comment: Why not just use `display:table-cell`?

Comment: Umm, genius...  I've never used that before and now I have NO idea why.  Please answer so I can give you points.

Comment: Oh, except now I can't make it 100% wide... still working on it.

Comment: Problem #1 is "So I'm simulating a table layout with a div and a couple spans inside it"

Comment: You're supposed to use a real `<table>` for tabular data. That data you have there looks suspiciously tabular.

Comment: @thirtydot: Unfortunately I'm just the UX guy and I don't have much say over the code itself.  I just get CSS classes for everything and do what I can :)

Comment: I appreciate that, but you really should try to educate your colleagues. Anyway, I think I know how you can do this, do you still need an answer? By "indent" what do you mean? More indented than the first line, or equally indented?

Comment: Honestly using the display property to set them all to table/table-row/table-cell worked perfectly.  The only issue I"m having now is making them all 100% width without a horizontal scrollbar, but I think I just have an issue somewhere above those elements causing it not to behave properly.  In essence, I'm waiting on @sdleihssirhc to post his comment as an answer so I can select it.

Comment: Oh, and apparently IE7 doesn't like the table display in CSS...

Comment: The answer you're waiting for has already been posted by @sdleihssirhc, but then he deleted it for some reason.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Check this out: **http://jsfiddle.net/2Wbuv/2/**

```css
.display-element {
}

.display-label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

.display-field {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 50px;
  text-indent: -50px;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 200px; /* for testing purposes only */
}
```

```html
<div class="display-element">
  <span class="display-label">Field 1</span>
  <span class="display-field">This is my string of data, some times it is pretty long.  Sometimes it is not.  This one is.</span>
</div>
<div class="display-element">
  <span class="display-label">Field 2</span>
  <span class="display-field">This is another string of data.</span>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem with this (making them both inline-block) is that it puts the first line down on the next line.  Remove the width of the second span and you'll see what I mean (or just make your window less than 300 pixels wide).

Comment: If you don't give `.display-field` a fixed width, which also requires the switch from inline to inline-block since it's a span element, you need to make it emulate a table cell using the non-cross-browser-compatible `display: table-cell`. Alternatively, and this is the way I would go, use an actual table.

Answer (score 18):

It sounds like you want a hanging indent. CSS something like this should do the trick:

```
.hanging-indent
{
  text-indent : -3em ;
  margin-left :  3em ;
}
```

But since your `<span>` is an inline element, the text-indent property, as well as other CSS properties pertaining to a block, is meaningless.

Answer (score 4):

The [CSS 3 draft specifies a hanging indent](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-text-3/#text-indent-property). If supported by Browsers, the following should work:

```
.hanging-indent
{
  text-indent: 3em hanging each-line;
}
```

Unfortunately neither `hanging` nor `each-line` values are [currently supported in modern browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/text-indent#Browser_compatibility) as the specification for [CSS Text Module Level 3](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-text-3/#text-indent) is still a Draft.

The feature is implemented with a browser specific prefix for [WebKit](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=112755) and [Chromium](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=360958). For [Firefox there is an open Bug you may vote on](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=784648).

Comment: How does this answer the question, when it doesn't work ?

Comment: As mentioned in the answer, the feature is implemented, but you need to use browser specific prefix for WebKit and Chromium. It seems nothing has changed in the last >8 years.

Comment: There isn't a browser-specific prefix for webkit and chrome.